# Vue test utils: how to setProps if they are used in mounted()

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm using jest / vue-test-utils to test a component, and I can't find a way to set props if they are used in mounted().

The component has one prop `queryFilter: { type: Object }` which is used within the `mounted()` hook.

My test looks like this:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Filter from '../../src/components/Filter.vue'
test('basic fail', async () => {
     const filter = mount(Filter);   
     await Filter.setProps({
        propsData: { queryFilter: { "foo": "bar" } }
    });
    expect(filter.vm.queryFilter).toEqual({ "foo": "bar" });
});
```

The error I get suggests that I tried to mount, triggering the mounted() hook, but props were not yet passed because `setProps` is called in the next line.

```
 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    > 75 |       let tables = Object.keys(this.queryFilter);
```

Of course, if I swap the two lines

```js
     await Filter.setProps({
        propsData: { queryFilter: { "foo": "bar" } }
    });
    const filter = mount(Filter);
```

then I get
`TypeError: _Filter.default.setProps is not a function`. Obviously.

Is there any way to use vue test in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly pass the props when mounting your component.

Example:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Filter from '../../src/components/Filter.vue'

test('basic fail', async () => {
    const filter = mount(Filter, {
        props: {
            queryFilter: { "foo": "bar" }
        }
    });   
    expect(filter.vm.queryFilter).toEqual({ "foo": "bar" });
});
```

For further details check out the [docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#props).